# Testing manual confirmation of Stripe's PaymentIntent

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to write tests for the new SCA Stripe integration using Elements & their API. I am stuck testing the manual confirmation of a `PaymentIntent`.

I am able to create the *PaymentIntent*. Usually it returns a `client_secret` that is then used with Stripe.js `handleCardAction()` which then returns a *PaymentIntent* id that I can confirm using `PaymentIntent::retrieve()`.

Since my tests are running on the PHP-side I am not able to fire the `handleCardAction()` and if I skip that step and use the `client_secret` I get this exception:

> Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException : No such payment_intent: pi_1FFIp5HU59FHbUqraBNXk9Br_secret_agKRuHJx4y83RFnjpKkGmd29W

How do I get a *PaymentIntent* ID that is ready for confirmation without using Stripe.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I could just use

```
        $intent = PaymentIntent::create([
            'payment_method'        => 'pm_card_threeDSecure2Required',
            'amount'                => 1000,
            'currency'              => 'USD',
            'description'           => 'blabla',
            'confirmation_method'   => 'manual',
            'confirm'               => true,
        ]);

        // $intent->id can be used with PaymentIntent::retrieve()
```